# Using append() from Jquery outside the HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use Jquery in a separate .JS file since keeping all JavaScript code out of the HTML document will increase the performance of loading the HTML document.

**For this example I am using "index.html" and "main.js"**

Below is index.html:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>append demo</title>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="testJS/main.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <p>I would like to say: </p>


<!-- CODE BELOW MUST BE REMOVED FROM THIS DOCUMENT -->
    <script>
    $( "p" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I would like to cut the  code from the html and insert it into main.js however the example below did not work for me:

main.js:

```
p.append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
```

I've also tried this with no success:

```
 $( "p" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
```

How could I fix this and what is the difference between having JavaScript inside  and having it inside a .js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the use of the `$( document ).ready()` function that JQuery provides something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
});
```

Here you can find more info: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the code in dom ready handler, because other wise when the code is executed the `p` element is still not added to the dom - it is because since the `main.js` is added before the `p` element in your markup, but anyway the safest option is to use dom ready handler for dom manipulation

```
jQuery(function($){
    $( "p" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When using external js you must wrap your code in document ready function like this

```
$(function(){
  $('p').append('<strong>Hello</strong>');
});
```

*Note - `$(function(){` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Arun P Johny, the problem is that the js code is executing before the DOM elements it depends on are ready.

Another solution is to change your external file so that it defines a function, which you would then call at the end of the body in your html file.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>append demo</title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="testJS/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>I would like to say: </p>

<script>
  writeText();
</script>
</body>
</html>


<!-- main.js -->

function writeText(){
  $( "p" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );
}
```